# WebSocket для мессенджера

Tags: php, node.js, chat

Для своего мессенджера я планировал использовать серверный вебсокет на языке PHP, но к сожалению, как я понимаю, PHP не подойдёт так как:
Php - синхронный язык программирования и если будет сразу много запросов к вебсокету от различный клиентов - то он попросту не будет некоторые запросы обрабатывать, ведь так..?

Получается чтобы избежать этой проблемы, мне необходимо будет использовать Асинхронный язык программирования, то есть: Nodejs

Или nodejs тоже не подойдёт? Подскажите пожалуйста новичку

Comment: Можете прочитать эту статью - https://habr.com/ru/post/150788/

Comment: http://socketo.me